# javascript split() regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a Javascript string.

```
var str = "an eye";
```

I want to split the string to get all the alphabets in an array **using split() and regex**. Meaning I want,

```
['a','n','e','y','e']
```

I used the following regex in **match()** to get the array:

```
var reg = /[a-z]/gi;
```

But, when I use the same regex in **split()**, it gives me an array of spaces.

```
["", "", " ", "", "", ""]
```

Please help me understand what i am missing here. I am new to both javascript and regex. TIA.

Comment: The implicit meaning of `split` is "split at".

Comment: @Imad062 split uses the match as a delimiter and returns the substrings from between the matches along with any captured groups from the regex matches. Both the answers posted using split will also return a space with the `n` (`"n "` instead of `"n"`). You should use match instead, and you can still call reverse on the array and anything else you want to do, such as `str.match(/[a-z]/gi).reverse().join('');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close! `split` will remove the items it matches and return the strings in-between each removed item as an array.

You want `match` instead, which returns an array of the items it matches:

```
str.match(/[a-z]/gi);
```

To get a better understanding of these methods, check out the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) documentation.

Comment: I want to use split() so that I can use reverse() and join() to reverse the string. I can get the results using match() but I can't get an understading of how split() works.

Comment: @Imad062 reverse and join are functions on Array.prototype. You can use them on any array whether it comes from `split`, `match` or anything else, like `[1,2,3].reverse().join(',') === '3,2,1'`.

Comment: Thanks For clarifying. I see that using match in these cases is more useful.

Comment: @Imad062 It's not only "more useful", it's a more appropriate function considering your goal.

Answer (score 3):

You've got spaces because when you split by char the `split()` function consumes that char. Use positive lookahead `(?=)` instead. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AICN3u/1/).

```js
var text = 'an eye'
console.log(text.split(/(?=[a-z])/i))
```